# Unable to consume WCF wshttpBinding service from phpClient

Tags: c#, php, wcf, soap-client

i can consume basichttp binding, but i am unable to consume services with ws-addressing.

These is how my request looks like.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetToken</a:Action>
  <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:5cf2a178-a552-4e64-a68f-4575445cfac0</a:MessageID>
  <a:ReplyTo>
    <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
  </a:ReplyTo>
</s:Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did try to invoke a WCF service with wshttpbinding and my request looks as shown

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue
</a:Action>
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:24f56d58-5ef5-41f4-8062-42934b9a36b5</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://localhost/WsHttpExample/Service1.svc</a:To>
</s:Header>
```

Its from a C# client. Now sure on how it is done in php. Hope it helps you.